# How to mix Unity Scene management and Network Scene Management?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

Hello i have an issue dealing with scene management and networkManager.

My game is as follow :

1. `HomeScene` (no network at all)
2. `LobbyScene` (`NetworkManager` component is created but scene is loaded using SceneManager of Unity)
3. `GameScene` (using `NetworkManager.SceneManager.Load("GameScene", LoadSceneMode.Single)` - this works fine so far)
4. `EndGameScene` (using `SceneManager` of unity - this doesn't work)

From `GameScene` (3) to `EndGameScene` (4) i don't need the network because i need to allow players to exit the `GameScene` without migrating all remaining players to `EndGameScene` so i can't use the `NetworkManager` to load the `GamScene`

- The `EndGameScene` has no network since it's a UI recap only.
- If the `Host` finishes the game first, then the remaining players must be able to complete the game in `GameScene` but the Host should see the `EndGameScene`.
- If a `Client` finishes the game, then it must go in `EndGameScene` and disappear from the `GameScene`

Currently with the [documentation](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/scenemanagement/scene-management-overview/), i am unable to find a solution to do this simple use case.

- If i load the `EndGameScene` for a client, it's loaded on top of the `GameScene` and messes up everything
- If i load the `EndGameScene` on a host, it's loading fine the `EndGameScene` but the clients are unable to finish the game in `GameScene`.